# Is it possible for `console.log` to output to a `p` element using electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want everything that console.log outputs to go to paragraph element in my index.html. I'm using electron.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which console? The browser console? A Node.js console?

Comment: You should be able to simply overwrite the command. `console.log = (...args) => { ... };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

```
const yourPtag = document.getElementById("yourPtag");
console.log = (...data) => yourPtag.append(" ", ...data);
console.log("test");
```

Now each time your log something, it will be added to the P tag of your choice specified in `yourPtag`

```js
const yourPtag = document.getElementById("yourPtag");
console.log = (...data) => yourPtag.append(" ", ...data);
console.log("test");
```

```html
<p id="yourPtag">Lorem...</p>
```